# Alternate (Free) to AOP PostSharp for method tracing (and exception)

Tags: c#, trace

I like to add tracing entering and leaving of every methods in classes. and also trace the arguments when an exception occurs. With PostSharp AOP, I don't need to put it in every method but just apply attributes. But I can't afford PostSharp.

Is there an alternate way to do this? Can Unity3D do that?

I am using log4net to log the message.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do Aspect Oriented Programming and Interception using Unity.

> Unity is a lightweight, extensible dependency injection container with
>   support for instance and type interception.

There is a great article from Dino Esposito: [Aspect-Oriented Programming, Interception and Unity 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490353.aspx)

> **Interception in Unity 2.0**
>
> The core idea of interception in Unity is enabling developers to customize the chain of calls that it takes
>   to invoke a method on an object. In other words, the Unity
>   interception mechanism captures calls being made to configured objects
>   and customizes the behavior of the target objects by adding some extra
>   code before, after or around the regular execution of methods.
>   Interception is essentially an extremely flexible approach to add new
>   behavior to an object at run time without touching its source code and
>   without affecting the behavior of classes in the same inheritance
>   path.

And also there is a great Patterns and Practices article about [Interception using Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx).
The example code at article performs logging using interception.

Comment: By the way, Unity3D is a game platform while you need Unity as described above.